# BMI calculator in GUI Java;

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I wanted to create a BMI calculator using GUI in Java. I'm very new to GUI and even Java. The calculator is suppose to display BMI with advice and even time and date. However, only the BMI is display while the rest can't.. I have been searching online on how to display results from if else condition online but to no avail.  This is my code;

```
public class BMI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final JButton JButton = null;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel heightLabel, weightLabel, BMILabel;
    private JTextField height, weight, result;
    private JButton calculate;
    String Height, Weight;
    double number1, number2, BMI;
    static String output = "Results";
    static int jopIcon = JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE;
    boolean bFlag = true; //state, true means no exception

    public BMI() {

        frame = new JFrame("BMI Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//create labels for the height and weight textfields 
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Your height in meters:");
        weightLabel = new JLabel("Your weight in kilograms: ");
//create a "this is your BMI" label
        BMILabel = new JLabel("Your BMI is ");
//create a result label to hold the BMI value
        result = new JTextField("");
//create a JTextField to hold the person's height in kilograms
        height = new JTextField(1);
//create a JTextField to hold the person's weight in metres
        weight = new JTextField(1);


        calculate = new JButton("Calculate BMI");

//set up the JPanel to go on the JFrame 
        panel = new JPanel();


        panel.add(heightLabel);
        panel.add(height);
//add the weight label and weight textfield to the panel
        panel.add(weightLabel);
        panel.add(weight);
//add the button to the panel

        panel.add(BMILabel);
//add the label that holds the result to the panel
        panel.add(result);
//add the panel to the frame 
        panel.add(calculate);
//add the BMI label to the panel



        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
        add(p1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);




        calculate.addActionListener(this);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);//important must HAVE@! if not GUI will not be display

    }

    public String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    public void calculateBMI(double number1, double number2) {
        try {
            BMI = number2 / ((number1) * 2);

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            output += "\n\n Whoa! Input error: must enter valid integers";//if exception comes    out, prepare error message
            jopIcon = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
        }
    }

    public void calculate() {
        Height = height.getText();
        Weight = weight.getText();//declare the Height string with Jtext height

        try {
            number1 = Double.parseDouble(Height);
            number2 = Double.parseDouble(Weight);//exception may come out

            calculateBMI(number1, number2);



        } finally {

            if (BMI >= 27.5) {

                output += "\n\n You're in the High Risk zone(UnHealthy). Please start losing weight! It's a MUST!";

            } else if (BMI <= 23 || BMI < 27.4) {

                output += "\n\n You're in the Moderate Risk zone. Please start going on diet and lose some weight";

            } else if (BMI <= 18.5 || BMI < 22.9) {
                output += " You're in the Low Risk zone(Healthy). Hopefully you can maintain this way! ^^";

            } else if (BMI < 18.4) {
                output += "\n\n You really need to start eating more. Too skinny and unhealthy for your body";

            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {




        BMI bmi = new BMI();



    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//call the calculate

        this.calculate();

        result.setText("" + BMI);

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to ask for free help, it's not too much to ask you to at least try to post well formatted code.

Comment: The solution is simply to add a component that will display the data you'd like to display to the GUI, *just the same as you're using to show the weight, height, and result*. You already know how to add these JTextField components, so it should be trivial for you to add more JTextFields or JLabels to show the additional information, no?

Comment: I don't see where you've tried to solve the problem yet, and so you may be premature in coming here. Why not first try to display the additional information, and only then come here with your attempt if your attempt doesn't work?

Comment: I'd start by having a read through [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Would also consider finding examples of layouts you like and trying to replicate them.  Try using compound panels for more complex layouts

Comment: That's a lot of code to go through.  Mind [cutting that down a bit?](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'd settle for descent naming conventions :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: amen! But one request at a time. :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I wanted it to display in the same results JTextField.. I tried changing output+= to results= but error.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will start reading those.. Thanks..

Comment: @MuhammadKhair: output is a String, and adding another String to it will do nothing to your display. What you need to do is use the String to set the text of a JTextField or a JLabel. This will require that you call the `setText(...)` method on the key one of these components.

Comment: @makoto basically, how to display time into the results?
 public String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

 Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//call the calculate

        this.calculate();

        result.setText("" + BMI);

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

Comment: If all you're concerned with is displaying time in your results, then why do we need to look through hundreds of lines of code? That's what I mean by cutting it down; only focus on the problem area of the code.   It makes it easier for you to debug and for us to answer. :)

Comment: @Makoto I'm sorry.. I just finished reading about code cleaning. Yea, basically about date and time and also the if else condition which was not working just now. but michael_s already help to answer the error for if else.

Comment: You should also drop the `extends JFrame`. This is unnecessary and is much error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    calculate();
    result.setText(output);
}
```

The result should be of type JTextArea however line wrap should be set:

```
result = new JTextArea();
result.setLineWrap(true);
```

And you should think about implementing the ActionListener in an anonymous class rather than directly in the frame class (especially when you would like add some other buttons or checkboxes)

```
calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        calculate();
        result.setText(output);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! That helps.. Finally my if else condition can display. So its actually the same like how I get BMI inside.. I understand now.. :D